# Why does my click counter only count the first click?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have a website that does wiki speed runs. I have a mode that is called wiki golf. the goal of the game is to get to the jesus wikipedia page in under 5 clicks from a random page. Right now this code is working, but only runs once. (the click counter only goes to one and then stops.) The code is counting how many times you click inside of an iframe.

```
    <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js">

    </script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/game/game.css">
    <script src="/game/game.js">

    </script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">


    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/apple-touch-icon.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/favicon-32x32.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/favicon-16x16.png">
    <link rel="manifest" href="/site.webmanifest">


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-9usAa10IRO0HhonpyAIVpjrylPvoDwiPUiKdWk5t3PyolY1cOd4DSE0Ga+ri4AuTroPR5aQvXU9xC6qOPnzFeg=="
     crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

</head>
<div id="message"></div>
<div id="invisible_layer">

</div>
<iframe src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random"  id="mainFrame" style="position:relative; top:0; left:0; bottom:0; right:0; width:100%; height:80%; border:none; margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; z-index:999999;"></iframe>
</div>
<title> Wiki Golf | WikiRun </title>


<style>
    #invisible_layer {
        position: absolute;
        background-color: trasparent;
        width: 500px;
        height: 300px;
    }
</style>

</html>
<div class="stopwatch">
    <p>
        <h1>
            <b> Good Luck!! </b>
   </h1>
  </p>
  </div> 
  <p>Clicks: <a id="bellow">0</a></p>
</a>


  <script>
  let count = 0;
  
var myConfObj = {
  iframeMouseOver : true
}
window.addEventListener('blur',function(){
  if(myConfObj.iframeMouseOver){
    count += 1;
     document.getElementById("bellow").innerHTML = count;

  }
});


document.getElementById('mainFrame').addEventListener('mouseover',function(){
   myConfObj.iframeMouseOver = true;
});
document.getElementById('mainFrame').addEventListener('mouseout',function(){
    myConfObj.iframeMouseOver = false;
});
</script>

</script>
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You have multiple `<head>` tags, you have `</body>` without `<body>`

Comment: Where is the `ClickUp()` function defined?

Comment: I updated my code but it still is not working.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're triggering the click count increase on a "blur" event, which, I suppose, only fires once when you first click into the iframe and then never again because the iframe is still focused. Why don't you use a simple "click" event instead?

```js
document.querySelector('iframe').addEventListener('click',function(){
  if(myConfObj.iframeMouseOver){
    count += 1;
     document.getElementById("bellow").innerHTML = count;

  }
});
```

Comment: The OP has an `onclick` attribute on the `iframe` element already...

Comment: Yeah but that doesn't seem to be going anywhere.

Comment: ... and you wouldn't get any rep from actually helping the OP with the code they have. ;P

Comment: I tried that but then it would not even update once

Comment: Here is the website that I am making. To get to the page click the SinglePlayer button, then the wikigolf button then start. https://WikiRun.dubiscoding.repl.co

Comment: I see where you are coming from @DavidsKanal but it is an Iframe. The Iframe cant see when you click into it because I dont own the frame. Someone told me maybe add an invisable div but I dont know how to do that. the new link is wikiruns.com if you want to see for yourself